# Maximum distance for sensor

Tags: sensors, esp32

I'm creating a project with some ESP32's running off PoE and I need to add some temperature/humidity sensors up to 5m away from the ESP chip

I assume there is a maximum cable distance?

What is the best way to overcome this distance, preferably without having to inject power or use WiFi?

Comment: What sensor do you have exactly?

Comment: I haven't picked one for this project yet, thought I should work out the limitations first

Comment: The limitations are defined by how the device communicates. How the device communicates is defined by what the device is. You need to look for a device that fits your criteria. FYI: digital is often more reliable over long distances than analogue, and different digital protocols have better long distance reliability than others.

Comment: Thinking about these
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000125526434.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.18cf23fcVrprv3&algo_pvid=c1feb228-eb55-4733-8f4d-98797185eb30&algo_exp_id=c1feb228-eb55-4733-8f4d-98797185eb30-2

Comment: That could do the trick, although I don't know what exact type that is. Something with an I2C interface (like BMEXXX/BMPXXX) should work reasonably with 5m of cable. I would rather not try DHT11's.

Comment: Also, please frame your project.  For instance, if you are making 100s I2C temper sensors products, some will certainly not work over meters distance as I2C was designed to be used between chip on the same PCB.  Maybe in the same case.  For that matter, if you are willing to spend the money and convert I2C or enhance it with additional HW you can get many meters out of the physical layer.

Comment: FWIW SparkFun has an I2C extension system based on NXP's PCA9615.

Comment: I have successfully tested different I2C devices with 10m of cable. So it _can_ work, but probably is not guaranteed to.

Comment: I would use an lm334 as a temp-dependent constant current source, then measure the voltage it produces on a fixed resistor with the ADC; cable length is then _completely_ irrelevant to the equation (could be a mile) as series circuits have identical current at all node points. You could also use a PTC or NTC thermistor as a divider to feed a BJT's base as a very simple dynamic current source.